# Divide records in 2 and 4 per row in foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I want to divide my records in 2 and 4 records per row. Like :

```
--- start for loop -----

<div>record 1 record 2</div>

<div>record 3 record 4 record 5 record 6</div>

<div>record 1 record 2</div>

<div>record 3 record 4 record 5 record 6</div>
 --- end for loop -----
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite easy using a modulus and some loops

```
$maxrows=100;
for( $i=0; $i < $maxrows; $i++ ){/* your main loop */

    echo '<div>';
    if( $i % 2 == 0 ){/* two records per div */
        for( $j=0; $j < 2; $j++ ) echo ' record_'.( $j+1 );
    } else { /* 4 records per div */
        for( $j=2; $j < 6; $j++ ) echo ' record_'.( $j+1 ); 
    }
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Comment: Thanks RamRaider, But my array is something like : $array = array('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11', 'col12'); So how i can do it with this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code for the same

```
 <?php
$limit = 2
$count = 1;
foreach($items as $item)
{
  if($count==1){ ?> <div> <?php }

  echo $item;
  $count++;

  if($count>$limit){?> </div> <?php 
  $count = 1;
  $limit = ($limit==2)? 4:2; 
} 

}
?>
```